# z-index a pseudo-element box-shadow behind a parent element

Tags: html, css, z-index, box-shadow

I'm trying to place the `:before`,`:after` `box-shadow` behind the button. But the transition is starting in front of the a tag. For my works CMS, I'll need all the properties to be on the a tag.

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Join Today</a>


.btn{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #8ec656;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px #d2d2d2 solid;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: box-shadow .4s;
}
.btn:hover{
  background: #6b9640;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -22px 13px 0px #84b652, inset 0px 2px 5px 0px #84b652;
}
.btn:before,
.btn:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 9px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 88%;
  top: 73%;
  transition: box-shadow .4s;
}
.btn:hover:before,
.btn:hover:after{
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3aj5muyu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.btn:before,
.btn:after{
  transition: .6s;
  content: "";
  box-shadow: 0 28px 17px -3px #777;
  width: 84%;
  height: 11px;
  top: 48%;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.btn:hover:before,
.btn:hover:after{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This is what I had to settle with. Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.btn` establishes a stacking context, so its background will always be at the back of its contents. The [back-to-front order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) is

> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

To fix it, `.btn` shouldn't establish a stacking context. Move the following properties to a wrapper:

```css
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

```css
.btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}
.btn{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #8ec656;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px #d2d2d2 solid;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: box-shadow .4s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover{
  background: #6b9640;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -22px 13px 0px #84b652, inset 0px 2px 5px 0px #84b652;
}
.btn:before,
.btn:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 9px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 88%;
  top: 73%;
  transition: box-shadow .4s;
}
.btn:hover:before,
.btn:hover:after{
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Join Today</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no way around this? For our CMS I'll need all the properties on the a tag.

Comment: @ColinLeahy Instead of an outer wrapper, you can add an inner wrapper, or a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this working example:

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: 1; */
  display: inline-block;
  
  background-color: #8ec656;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px #d2d2d2 solid;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  transition: box-shadow .4s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn > span {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
}

.btn:hover{
  background: #6b9640;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -22px 13px 0px #84b652, inset 0px 2px 5px 0px #84b652;
}
.btn:before,
.btn:after{
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 9px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 88%;
  top: 73%;
  transition: box-shadow .4s;
}
.btn:hover:before,
.btn:hover:after{
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn"><span>Join Today</span></a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7argwcje/

That's because before and after elements are effectively children of the .btn element and siblings of the plain text (Join today). So you have no way to force the text to be on front.

These are the changes:

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: 1; */
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #8ec656;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px #d2d2d2 solid;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  transition: box-shadow .4s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn > span {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Basically transferred some properties from `.btn` to a wrapper span element.

Notice that the z-indexes are no longer necessary.